# Generate Excel Report in Android with Sqlite Database

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I have new hand on Android. I have made a report using `ListView` which is divided into three columns named `DateTime`, `OnOffStatus`, `AlarmImage`.

It work fine and looks good enough but now I want to export this table data to Excel format. Is it possible or not and how?

thanks in advance
Om Parkash Kaushik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Export sqlite To excel/csv file in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448001/how-to-implement-export-sqlite-to-excel-csv-file-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Start of by looking at http://poi.apache.org/ and http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html
I use this library to all of my excel reports.

**Start of by creating a Workbook:**

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Map<String, CellStyle> styles = createStyles(workbook);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
```

**Setup some style:**

```
private static Map<String, CellStyle> createStyles(Workbook wb) {

Map<String, CellStyle> styles = new HashMap<String, CellStyle>();
CellStyle style;
Font monthFont = wb.createFont();
monthFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 11);
monthFont.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
style.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_50_PERCENT.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
style.setFont(monthFont);
style.setWrapText(true);

styles.put("header", style);
style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
style.setWrapText(true);
style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_NONE);
style.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_NONE);
style.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_NONE);
style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_NONE);
styles.put("cell", style);
    return styles;
}
```

**Then setup a header row:**

```
private static final String[] article_headers = {"header1", "header2"};

// Header row
Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
headerRow.setHeightInPoints(40);
Cell headerCell;

for (int i = 0; i < article_headers.length; i++) {
    headerCell = headerRow.createCell(i);
    headerCell.setCellValue(article_headers[i]);
    headerCell.setCellStyle(styles.get("header"));
}
```

And then you continue with the rows by setting their style and value.

Hope this helps and if you find this helpful, remember to accept.

// Jakob

Comment: I got the "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" error when I run this code in my application.Can you guide me how to remove this error from my code.I have added poi-3.9-20121203.jar file in my project.