# Is it possible to create an excel spreadsheet through Android Studio?

Tags: java, excel, android-studio, apache-poi, docx4j

I am looking to make an app that allows users to enter information into several fields, and when they submit, the data is formatted into an excel file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448001/how-to-implement-export-sqlite-to-excel-csv-file-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything to create is possible. You might use TableLayout and TableRows to add new textviews columns, and also you should use database to save user's input